# UDP transmit performance

Tags: udp

I have an application that transmits some data in a loop. 
Underlying protocol is UDP on WinSock. If I don't add sleep(1ms) after each transmit operation most  of the data is not sent (or wireshark can not capture it) Have you experienced such a behavour that UDP does not handle repetitive sending in a loop ?

Regards

Tugrul

Comment: Have you checked the return value from the send function?

Comment: actually there is a TCP Client class on top of WinSock and i check it against some specific error codes (but not against all i think)

Comment: This sounds like non-blocking sockets, i.e. buffer overflow.

Comment: I have this behavior too. Any luck in finding answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should check the return values when you send data to check if data is successfully sent or not.
Second thing, This can happen internal buffer of UDP cannot accommodate more data because previous data is yet not transmitted. So the simplest solution is that each time before send the data you should check if your UDP socket is writable or not. You can do it by calling "select" or "poll" on that UDP socket.

Comment: What do you mean??? You are saying there is TCP and then underlying UDP??? I can't get that. Can you please explain?? UDP and TCP both work on same network layer and you can't run TCP over UDP or vice verse. You must be confusing up something. Please explain it a little.